# Old Blogger URL does not redirect to new URL

Tags: blogger

I have just changed my blogspot URL to a new address, going to 'Errors and Redirection' in settings, typing in my old URL to be redirected to my new URL (I also did click 'permanent'), however nothing has happened. When I type the URL of my old blogspot.com in the search engine, all I get is 'Blog has not been found'. How do I fix this problem? There is a lot of people who only have my old address and it is important to have the site redirected to the new one.

Please help me solve this.

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately for you, that's not how Bloggers Error's and Redirections > Custom Redirects works:   this tool can only be used to redirect one post or page within the blog's "domain" to another one within the same domain.

Eg you can redirect

> **from**  www.myBlog.blogspot.com/2015/01/original-title.html
>   **to**  www.myBlog.blogspot.com/2015/06/different-title.html

Blogger does not provide any tool to let you redirect

> **from**  www.myOldBlog.blogspot.com
>   **to**    www.myNewBlog.blogspot.com

The only suggestion I can make is to set up a new blog, with the old blog's URL, and just put one post on it.  That post shoudl re-direct people to your new address, and tell them to update their bookmarks.   And then use Error's and Redirections > Custom Page Not Found   to re-direct everyone to that one post.